# Convert uint16 to byte array

Tags: c, arrays, hex

let's say I have an array:

```
uint16 my_uint16_Array[6] = {0x1A20, 0x1A35, 0X1AEC, 0x1AB8, 0x1A5D, 0x1AF3}
```

I want to convert this array to an byte array in order to have:

```
uint8 my_uint8_Array[12] = {0x1A, 0x20, 0x1A, 0x35, 0X1A, 0xEC, 0x1A, 0xB8, 0x1A, 0x5D, 0x1A, 0xF3}
```

What is the fastest way to do it in c?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What is your platform? On Intel the int16 will be stored as `0x20, 0x1A` and so you need to physically swap or copy the individual bytes to the int8 array. Would you want your int16 array as `{0x20, 0x1A,...}` then a simple union or cast would suffice.

Comment: For each value in `my_uint16_Array`: split it in two bytes using bitshift and mask, then add the two bytes into `my_uint8_Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `memcpy` will not sufficient for this task on little endian machine. In that case I would do this. Although I not guarantee this is the fastest way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t my_uint16_Array[6] = {0x1A20, 0x1A35, 0X1AEC, 0x1AB8, 0x1A5D, 0x1AF3};
    uint8_t my_uint8_Array[12];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        my_uint8_Array[i << 1] = my_uint16_Array[i] >> 8;
        my_uint8_Array[(i << 1) + 1] = my_uint16_Array[i] & 0xFF;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        printf("0x%x ", my_uint8_Array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0x1a 0x20 0x1a 0x35 0x1a 0xec 0x1a 0xb8 0x1a 0x5d 0x1a 0xf3
```

Another version which seem to produce less assembly instruction with MSP430 architecture with gcc 6.2.1 and `-O3` flag. Also this is somewhat closer what `x86` will actually do after optimization with the above code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t my_uint16_Array[6] = {0x1A20, 0x1A35, 0X1AEC, 0x1AB8, 0x1A5D, 0x1AF3};
    uint8_t my_uint8_Array[12];

    uint8_t *highBytePtr = (uint8_t*) my_uint16_Array;
    uint8_t *lowBytePtr = (uint8_t*) my_uint16_Array;
    highBytePtr++;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i += 2, highBytePtr += 2, lowBytePtr += 2)
    {
        my_uint8_Array[i] = *highBytePtr;
        my_uint8_Array[i + 1] = *lowBytePtr;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        printf("0x%x ", my_uint8_Array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i << 1` is not wrong, but you should rather write `i * 2` and let the compiler do such optimisations. 20 years ago good C compilers already did this kind of optimisation, let alone modern compilers. [Check here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/hHmESs): even with -O0 (no optimisation) `i<<1` and `i*2` are compiled into the same code

Comment: The second proposal with casting the `uint16_t`  array to `uint8_t*` is platform dependent. It will give different results on big endian and little endian systems.

Comment: @Bodo Note that my proposed solutions are for little endian machines.

Comment: The first solution should work independently from the endianness. Writing code that depends on the endianness should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score -1):

you can declare a uint8_t pointer and just "reinterpret" the data as a uint8_t array. But beware of endianness! the ordering may not in the way you expect it to be:

```
uint8_t *bytePointer = (uint8_t*) my_uint16_Array;
for(uint8_t i=0; i< sizeof(my_uint16_Array); i++) {
    printf("%02X, ", bytePointer[i]);
}
```

On a little endian machine you get this output:

> 20, 1A, 35, 1A, EC, 1A, B8, 1A, 5D, 1A, F3, 1A

On a big endian machine, all value pairs are flipped:

> 1A, 20, 1A 35, 1A, EC, 1AB8, 1A, 5D, 1A, F3

Comment: Rather, they are flipped on the little endian machine, compared to the original data stream.